# Remove ANSI codes from string with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Given the following string:

```
"foo\e[38;5;1mbar\e[0mbaz"
```

How can I remove both `\e[38;5;19m` and `\e[0m` with sed without knowing the exact values of the numbers within those strings?
Expected output:

```
foobarbaz
```

I have the following sed line, which matches the first string:

```
# regex: \\e\[[^/]*m
sed -E 's/\\e\[[^/]*m//g'
```

This returns `sed: 1: unbalanced brackets ([])`.
How can I get rid of both strings where the numbers are not known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. This should do the job:

```
$ echo "foo\e[38;5;1mbar\e[0mbaz" | sed -E 's/\\e[^\\]*m//g'
# foobarbaz
```